# Download file without taking ownership

Tags: development, document-library

I have a few files in a document library which were never checked-in. I have that list of files available through the document library settings page or in c# using `SPDocumentLibrary.CheckedOutFiles`

Is there a way that I can download those files without taking their ownership via C#.

Comment: yes you can download the document library files via C# but what do you exactly mean by without taking their ownership?

Comment: @ZakirHC please have a look at `SPCheckedOutFile`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have identified the files you need, why not just copying them as byte Arrays ? Just call the following method with the full file URL

```
public static byte[] GetBytesFromFile(string fullFilePath)
{
    FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't work as 1. URI formats are not supported by File.OpenRead. 2. Even if it does, it is returning 404.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised. It works very fine for me (O365 tenant) when I state the full file URL (https included).